# JsonSerializer.Deserialize can't convert number

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to convert string to object using this command:

```cs
var body = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LoginResponse>(bodyString);
```

This is the `LoginResponse`:

```
class LoginResponse
{
  public string Token { get; set; }
  public int Expires { get; set; }
}
```

This is how the response looks:

```
{"token":"longstring","expires":1676226606506}
```

It throws this error:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException
  Message=The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.expires | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 220.
  Source=System.Text.Json
```

How do I fix the error and make `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` return an object?

Comment: Replace `int` to `long`.

Comment: [Characteristics of the integral types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#characteristics-of-the-integral-types). Your value just does not "fit" into "int".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to replace int with long, because 1676226606506 bigger then int.MaxValue